# Django admin form validation

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

In my django app, I want to add a validation to the automatically generated admin form of a model. I want to raise a `ValidationError` if the attribute `title` equals "test". I have tried the following in `admin.py`, but nothing happens if the title is "test". Could anyone help, please?

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms import ModelForm, ValidationError

from .models import MyModel

class MyModelAdminForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        title = cleaned_data.get('title')
        if title == 'test':
            raise forms.ValidationError('invalid!')
        return cleaned_data

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelAdminForm

admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not register the `MyModel` model with the `MyModelAdmin` class. You do that with:

`admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)`

Also, because the `clean` method checks only one field (`title`), you should use the method `clean_title` and raise the `ValidationError` inside there. No need for `clean()`.

Example:

```
def clean_title(self):
    title = self.cleaned_data['title']
    if title == 'test':
        raise forms.ValidationError('invalid!')
    return title
```